# How can I create a statistics tool with PHP/MySQL from existing Timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing MySQL table with various fields.

userid | name | ... | timestamp

I'd like to have a statistics tool which shows me how many entrys were made in a specific day and in which hour of that day.

---

Example:

Statistics for: 02-24-2011

Total entrys: XXXXX

Hour 1: XX //Which should be 12 AM to 1 AM

Hour 2: XX

Hour 3: XX
...

---

How can this be done? Thanks for all your help!

DC

Comment: Have you tried __anything__ so far, or are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: Ive tried to fetch the timestamps one by one by the first XXXXX digits to see the date, but it definitely takes too long. maybe you can give me a hint - i know php fairly good, but didn't have to deal with sth like this before. i guess it reuqires a specific sql query to get all entrys from a specific timerange.

Comment: EDIT: could a) be the solution for my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615521/parsing-timestamps-do-it-in-mysql-or-in-php

Comment: As the field i saved as a PHP timestamp so i probably can't use that specific SQL query. I guess i have to convert them to a date in PHP one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT HOUR( timestamp ) AS the_hour, COUNT(*) AS entries 
FROM your_table
WHERE DATE( timestamp ) = NOW()
GROUP BY HOUR( timestamp )
```

it will return counters hour by hour from today (change NOW() if need to change day), if no entry in specific hour -> no record,

Answer (score 0):

Try that

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m-%d-%Y'), COUNT(userid) FROM your_table_name
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '2011-02-24 00:00:00' AND   DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= '2011-02-24 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H')